# If there are values in specific cells, I need them to subtract from one main cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, equations

I need to find an equation so if there are any values from B2-R2 it will subtract 1 from W2 which needs to start at a value of 17.

For example, if the value of D2 is 6 it will subtract 1 from W2. Then if there is a value of 3 in H2, it will subtract 1 from W2's new value.

So if there is a value in B2 through R2, the value of W2 should be 0.

I'm new to excel and am having a hard time figuring this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want

```
=17-COUNTA(B2:R2)
```

where `COUNTA()` counts the non-empty (non-blank) cells in a range. 
But part of your question makes it sound like
you are putting a value of `17` into cell `W2` and then modifying (decrementing) that cell. 
That's not possible with formulas; to actually change a cell you need to use VBA.

Comment: Anybody who has a different answer *should post **a different answer***. If your answer uses a function whose operation is less obvious than `COUNT` (something like `SUMPRODUCT`, for example), include an explanation of how it works in your answer.

Comment: @Russ - G-Man makes a good point about VBA.  To expand a little, if you are new to Excel, you may think of solutions in terms of how you would manually approach the problem.  There are two ways to get a value into a cell.  You can pre-place a formula, which will update as the source data changes, or you can place a value into a cell or manipulate it in real time with VBA as the result of some trigger action.  If you only care that the result in W2 reflects what is in B2:R2, even if that changes, you can use formulas.  If you need to control when or how W2 gets updated, you would use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are truly blank or if they contain formulas that may return empty strings (e.g. "") then the [COUNTBLANK function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countblank-HP005209028.aspx) has been available since at least Excel 2003. `COUNTBLANK` will count an empty string as a blank while `COUNTA` will count the empty string as a value. In W2 use the following formula.

`=COUNTBLANK(B2:R2)`

When all of the cells in the B2:R2 range are blank (or empty strings) the result will be 17. As any cell in that range gets a value typed in (or a formula produce s a result) the 17 gets reduced by 1 for each cell.